# Simple-Expand (JQuery) not working in Internet Explorer 11 but works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running XAMPP on a Windows box. Below is my test file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>very nice file</title>
</head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<body>
<a class="expander" href="#">click me</a>
<div class="content">
    I WANT TO HIDE THISSSS.
</div>

</body>
</html>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redhotsly/simple-expand/master/src/simple-expand.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.expander').simpleexpand();
           });
    </script>
```

When I surf to that file in Internet Explorer, I see 'click me' and 'I WANT TO HIDE THISSSS'. When I surf to it in other browsers, I see 'click me', and clicking it will un-hide the 'I WANT TO HIDE THISSSS' text.

Searched all night and still have nothing! Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: try using 2.4 version or jquery or something like that

Comment: jquery can handle toggling a div without the use of another plugin. also SO generally doesn't respond well to needless swearing in a post

Comment: Oh my goodness, I had this file laden with profanity because I was so frustrated. I thought I had removed all of it before posting it here. Edited! Please accept my apology community! :D

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need that expander? If you are just to hide/show a content. You can create one with few lines of code since you are using jquery

You can try this simple fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/yzdthzhL/

you can play the code you want.

and by the way. I'm not sure if this is helpful or not but. It would nice to add your script inside your html document.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="somelibrarieshere"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script src="somelibrarieshere"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and not outside html block. It's better that way. :) Have a great day pal.

Comment: Hello Edang!! Thanks for the reply. Your code looks great, however yes - I will need an expander. You see, I have a DIV that has a clear border. And when you expand the DIV, I'd like for the actual height/width of it to increase, to make room for the hidden content to be revealed.